# if statements leading to unresolved identifier

Tags: swift, if-statement

According to Xcode, the "query" in the cloud kit perform function alerts me that "query" is an unresolved identifier. I know this issue revolves around the if statements because this code works if "query" is clearly defined by one record type. However, I do not understand why query is unresolved in this situation, when all potential queries are accounted for.

```
 if newindex.row == 5
    {
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "mexican", predicate: predicate)
    }
    if newindex.row == 6
    {
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "seafood", predicate: predicate)
    }
    else if newindex.row == 7
    {
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "steakhouses", predicate: predicate)
    }


    publicDB.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil)
```

Comment: `query` is out of scope.

Comment: It could be because you haven't defined query outside of the if statements so there could be a case where query will be undefined (for example, when newindex.row is 8.

Comment: how would I go about fixing this undefined scope issue?

Comment: It's really time to use a `switch` statement when you have this much `if` chaining. That also helps identify when you've missed a possible outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare `query` outside the if-statements if you want it to be accessible outside them. Your if-chain can also be replaced with a cleaner switch-statement. For example:

```
let query: CKQuery

switch newindex.row {
    case 5: query = CKQuery(recordType: "mexican", predicate: predicate)
    case 6: query = CKQuery(recordType: "seafood", predicate: predicate)
    case 7: query = CKQuery(recordType: "steakhouses", predicate: predicate)
    default: preconditionFailure("unreachable")
}

publicDB.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable outside the `if` scope and modify it in `if` statement.

```
var query = nil
if newindex.row == 5 {
    query = CKQuery(recordType: "mexican", predicate: predicate)
} else if newindex.row == 6 {
    query = CKQuery(recordType: "seafood", predicate: predicate)
} else if newindex.row == 7 {
    query = CKQuery(recordType: "steakhouses", predicate: predicate)
}

if let query = query { // unwrap the nilable variable
    publicDB.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to give a concise general answer for:

> However, I do not understand why query is unresolved in this situation, when all potential queries are accounted for.

I, evidently, do this type of setup quite often in other languages and I was irritated Swift didn't seem to support it.

I was also unsure if declaring the variable above the if/else block would make it so I couldn't use `let` to make my variable immutable.

So I was pleasantly surprised that defining the type of the variable without a value still allows for the variable to be set in the if/else block and keep immutability:

```
let foo: String

if true {
    foo = "bar"
} else {
    foo = "che"
}

foo = "baz" // ERROR: immutable value 'foo' may only be initialized once
```